# .Net Responsive Gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I'm working with an asp.net site with Bootstrap. There is an extension installed from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547745/Add-Responsive-Behaviour-to-a-GridView-in-ASP-NET to handle gridview responsiveness within an update panel.

It's effective when testing from a laptop/pc, but fails to work when actually viewing a page with a gridview via a phone. The one I tested with is an android.

What it does: Creates two table instances, one the becomes a static column, one that has an overflow container that contains scrollable data.

To see a sample of a gridview using this code, go to http://dev6.web2market.com/.
Click "My Account" link in header. 
Credentials... 
Username: testing@testing.com
Password: SoTesting1!
Resize browser to a width of 600px or less so the script kicks in. Source code will show both tables - static column and then the scrollable table in the overflow container.

I could really use a push in the right direction. I posted the full javascript file here: http://jsfiddle.net/jcw2m/9fquzoxj/. A small sample (required to share fiddle link):

```js
// Detect overflow by checking the table width against that of its parent tree
        function setupResponsiveTable(table) {
            tableWidth = table.width();
            if (table.parent().hasClass(_overflowContainer)) {
                tableWidth += $('.' + _staticContainer).width();
            }

            isResponsive = false;
            table.parents().each(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass(_overflowContainer)
     && tableWidth > $(this).width()
     
    ) {
                    isResponsive = true;
     

                    // break out of each
                    return (false);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who needs this. In jquery.responsivetable.js, around line 118, look for this code block:

```
                table.before(tableStatic);

            table.wrap(_divClass + _overflowContainer + '" style="float:left;' + _overflow + ':scroll;' + _overflow + '-y:hidden;"/>');
            tableStatic.wrap(_divClass + _staticContainer + '" style="float:left;"/>');

            if (options.scrollHintEnabled) {
                setupScrollHint(table, tos);
            }
            //This line added courtesy Marty. The class "table" is from bootstrap. When present on the table contained in the overflow div, it causes column headers to shift to the left instead of aligning with their respective column data. jc 12/17/14 
            ***table.removeClass("table");***           
        }
```

That last line "table.removeClass("table");" is what ended up doing the trick.